# DART server setup under Fedora

Tags: installation, server, dart, fedora-21

I want to configure a server running Fedora 21 to be able to server Dart app from the command line as well as on the home network.

I get the Dart SDK from www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/ choosing version 1.13.1. This gives me a zip that when extracted has a folder structure of

```
/dart-sdk
   /bin
   /include
   /lib
   /util
```

I can guess that I would drop the files that are in the /bin folder into /usr/bin but I am not sure of the other files under the folders include, lib and util. Should I create new folders under '/' for the files in these folders or should they be properly placed somewhere else?

Where should the files that are in the SDK download go when installing Dart on Fedora 21.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract to a proper directory and then symlink the files in `dart-sdk/bin` to `/usr/bin/...` or add the `dart-sdk/bin` directory to your path.